# Panels, panel node print header and footer

Tags: 7, panels

I use Panels [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and I've created Panel page, where I inserted Panel nodes.

Problem: Panel nodes have their own header and footer html tags that are printed. How to remove them? Any way to make it without custom template in code?

Answer (score 0):

I should use min-panel. Panel page and panel node both have page structure.